# Implement a reverb effect class in Naudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have a C# class with a reverb effect implementation based on the Schroeder algorithm. I would like to implement this to a custom NAudio class inheriting a ISampleProvider or a IWaveProvider.

Anyone could show me how I should adapt the "Apply Effect" method to get it working on NAudio? this is the main method of this class:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
internal float[] ApplyEffect(float[] inputSamples, int sampleRate, float delayInMilliseconds, float decayFactor, float mixPercent)
{
    int bufferSize = inputSamples.Length;

    //Method calls for the 4 Comb Filters in parallel. Defined at the bottom
    float[] combFilterSamples1 = CombFilter(inputSamples, bufferSize, delayInMilliseconds, decayFactor, sampleRate);
    float[] combFilterSamples2 = CombFilter(inputSamples, bufferSize, (delayInMilliseconds - 11.73f), (decayFactor - 0.1313f), sampleRate);
    float[] combFilterSamples3 = CombFilter(inputSamples, bufferSize, (delayInMilliseconds + 19.31f), (decayFactor - 0.2743f), sampleRate);
    float[] combFilterSamples4 = CombFilter(inputSamples, bufferSize, (delayInMilliseconds - 7.97f), (decayFactor - 0.31f), sampleRate);

    //Adding the 4 Comb Filters
    float[] outputComb = new float[bufferSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < outputComb.Length; i++)
    {
        outputComb[i] = ((combFilterSamples1[i] + combFilterSamples2[i] + combFilterSamples3[i] + combFilterSamples4[i]));
    }

    //Algorithm for Dry/Wet Mix in the output audio
    float[] mixAudio = new float[bufferSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mixAudio.Length; i++)
    {
        mixAudio[i] = ((100 - mixPercent) * inputSamples[i]) + (mixPercent * outputComb[i]);
    }

    //Method calls for 2 All Pass Filters. Defined at the bottom
    float[] allPassFilterSamples1 = AllPassFilter(mixAudio, bufferSize, sampleRate);
    float[] allPassFilterSamples2 = AllPassFilter(allPassFilterSamples1, bufferSize, sampleRate);

    return allPassFilterSamples2;
}
```

Thanks in advance!